# How do I rewrite an expression in sympy to follow a specific form to use for an equation?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm looking to reformat a Sympy expression from a form like:
[image: Sample Sympy equation]

to something like this:

[image: Desired Equation Format]

Getting in this form will help me do some important calculations quickly later on if I can isolate what A, B, and C will be in the second form from the first form. After over 3-4 hours of searching the internet, there is no documentation or such available to help solve this in terms of rewriting an expression in a certain form. The closest I found was the `.rewrite()` command, but that doesn't isolate the `sin()` and `cos()` together (unless there is some hidden way in that function that the documentation did not provide).

Thanks!

Comment: it would help if you format your question as copy pastable text. But something like `w = Wild("w"); collect(my_expression, [cos(w), sin(w)])` might help.

Answer (score 1):

Although this can probably be solved with matching, it sounds like you just want to collect the coefficients of `cos(th3)` and `sin(th3)`. I'll show a similar expression where collection on `cos(x)` and `sin(x)` is done:

```
>>> eq = 2*cos(x) + cos(x)*y + sin(x)*cos(y) + 3*sin(x) + pi
>>> gens = cos(x), sin(x)
>>> collect(eq, gens)
(y + 2)*cos(x) + (cos(y) + 3)*sin(x) + pi
>>> [_.coeff(i) for i in gens]
[y + 2, cos(y) + 3]
>>> reps = dict(zip(symbols('A B'), _))
>>> reps[C] = eq.as_independent(*gens, as_Add=True)[0]
>>> dict(reps)
{A: y + 2, B: cos(y) + 3, C: pi}
```

Writing this as a helper function which uses Poly to do collection and testing that no cross terms in generators exist gives:

```
def coeffs(eq, gens):
    c = Poly(eq, gens)
    co = [c.coeff_monomial(i) for i in gens]
    # alternative way to get constant term
    co.append(eq.xreplace(dict(zip(gens, [0]*len(gens)))))
    return dict(zip(numbered_symbols('C'), co))

>>> coeffs(eq, gens)
{C0: y + 2, C1: cos(y) + 3, C2: pi}
```